# How to multiply Image with kernel/filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

As you can see in image, how to multiply A and B  with stride 3x3?.
Can someone please explain to me how I can do that? Some code examples would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you are looking for is

```
Result = repmat(A,2,2) .* B;
```

[`repmat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) repeats the matrix `A` twice along each dimension. You can specify how many times to repeat the matrix based on the sizes of `A` and `B`, as long as `A` fits an integer number of times in `B`:

```
reps = size(B) ./ size(A);
assert(all(mod(reps,1)==0))
Result = repmat(A,reps) .* B;
```